# Select inline, document or external style sheet at run time for web page

Tags: css

**help me please**
**select one of the inline , document or external style sheet at run time for web page
  **

Comment: Can you please clarify?  "Run time" -- what do you mean by this?  Do you mean, have a stylesheet selector?

Comment: no
select one of inline,document or external style sheet for webpage

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/alternate/) provides several Javascript functions which allow you to switch stylesheets.  Hook that up to your `<select>`.